# Filling struct with data in file

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to fill a struct with the data of a file.

The file is separated with double dot like this:

```
string1:15
```

When I read the file and fill the fields of the struct with data I get a Segmentation Fault.

Here the struct file **character.h**:

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H_
#define CHARACTER_H_

typedef struct Character *Personaje;

struct Character{
        char name[20];
        int lvl;
};


extern void saveCharacter(char *name, int lvl);
extern Personaje *getCharacter();
extern char *toString(Personaje *pj);
#endif
```

and here the function in source file **character.c**:

```
Personaje *getCharacter(){
        FILE *fp;
        Personaje *salida = (Personaje*) malloc(sizeof(Personaje));
        fp = fopen("kprct", "rb");

        fscanf(fp, "%[A-Za-z]:%d", (*salida)->name, &((*salida)->lvl));
        printf("Linea: %s : %d\n", (*salida)->name, (*salida)->lvl);

        fclose(fp);
        return salida;

}
```

How can I fill the struct with the file data?

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc`&friends!

Comment: You do not limt the size of the array you read. That is an invitation to buffer overflow (aka: undefined behaviour).

Comment: there's no malloc for your `Character` struct anywhere if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hint: do not typecast a pointer to your struct, but the stuct itself. This is much less confusing and will avoid exactly the problem you are facing here: only allocate space for the pointer, not the struct.

Comment: `Personaje salida = malloc(sizeof(*salida));`..`fscanf(fp, "%[A-Za-z]:%d", salida->name, &salida->lvl); printf("Linea: %s : %d\n", salida->name, salida->lvl);`  also `Personaje getCharacter(void){`

Comment: Generally, for problems like this, try to use a debugger. It will tell you where exactly the segmentation fault occurs, which makes it much easier to find and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: do not typecast a pointer to your struct, but the stuct itself. This is much less confusing and will avoid exactly the problem you are facing here: only allocate space for the pointer, not the struct.

Also you are defining a `Character **`:

```
Personaje *salida = (Personaje*) malloc(sizeof(Personaje));
```

So: with the given type definitions:

```
Personaje salida = malloc(sizeof(*salida));
```

Note: using `*salida` in `sizeof` makes this term independent from the type of `salida`.

The rest of your code is also broken, as your functions also have one `*` too much whereever `Personaje` is involved.

A proper definition would be:

```
typedef struct {
        char name[20];
        int lvl;
} Personaje;     // or name the type just Character
```

Then, for the prototypes, use `Personaje *` as you already have. The `malloc`-line would be:

```
Personaje *salida = malloc(sizeof(*salida));
```

(Note: I did not have to change the `sizeof()`-argument.)

Additional issues:

- **Always** check the results of system functions, as they might report an error. `malloc` might return `NULL`, the file functions might report an error, too.
- **Always** restrict the number of chars `fscanf` reads into a char array! As it is now, it is an invitation to buffer overflow, aka *undefined behaviour*.
- Do not cast `void *` as used by `malloc`, `free`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the major problem here is

```
typedef struct Character *Personaje;
```

this way, you're making `Personaje` as a pointer already, and in the code, you're writing

```
  Personaje *salida
```

which creates a pointer to pointer. This is not required, an neither what you wanted, I think. I suggest, change your `typedef` to

```
typedef struct Character Personaje;
```

and all the access to the variable in `fscanf()` and `printf()`.

Also,

1. Please do not cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. Check for the return value of `fopen()` and `fscanf()` to ensure success.

Comment: I want to store only one Character, I think that's the problem. But I can't fix whit this.

Comment: @PepeFernandez: "I want to store only one Character" ??

Comment: @Olaf Don't forget sir, "character" is the structure itself... confusing at it's best :-)

Comment: You are right! Camel case ... (Although the name is not that badly choosen actually).

Comment: @PepeFernandez: It does not matter how many `Character`s you want to load/store actually. However, if you want to staore more of them, things get more complicated but the mechanism would be basically the same.